# How to resolve nested generic type using InjectionConstructor

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I have generic repository

```
interface IRepository<T>
{
}

class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public Repository(ILog<Repository<T>> log)
    {
    }
}
```

and generic log

```
interface ILog<T>
{
}
```

Now, I need to specify a constructor while injecting my repository as open generic type:

```
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(Repository<>),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ILog<>))));

// or

container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(Repository<>),
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ILog<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Repository<>)))));
```

When trying to resolve dependency, it fails due to *"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."* exception.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear. You can't use `InjectionConstructor` with open generic type (`typeof(ILog<>)`). The easiest fix for you will be just removing `InjectionConstructor` parameter because it's not required in this case.

There is no need to use `InjectionConstructor` here. Register dependencies as:

```
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(Repository<>));
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(ILog<>),
    typeof(Log<>));
```

Comment: I need to inject particular named log instance, how can you do that without specifying the parameters?

Comment: @EwanCoder You could inject `ILogFactory` which could create log for you.

Comment: @FCin This solution results in changing the design due to Unity container limitations. However I'll give it a try.